# How to assign a matrix to a cell of a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I'm working on matlab and try to assign a matrix to one cell of a cell array. However, there was always something wrong. Here is the code:

```
    C = {};
    myMatrix = xlsread('myexcelfile');
    C{'ID', 'info'} = myMatrix;
```

Then matlab prompted that

> "Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 12 results."

But if I don't use 'ID' and 'Info' but use '1' and '2' instead, the matrix could be assigned successfully.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: So why don't you use `C{1,2} = myMatrix`? (or whichever numbers you need instead of 1, 2) What result do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LuisMendo I want to obtain an array that whenever I input the users' names and IDs, I can get the corresponding information, which is stored in a matrix. That's why I have to use strings instead of numbers.

Comment: If you want to index by names you probably need a [`table`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), not a cell array. Cell arrays use numerical or logical indexing. (They _can_ be indexed with characters, but that doesn't give the result you want). See some examples of indexing into tables [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo Alright. Thank you. Maybe I should try another way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have got three persons and each one has got a name and ID number and the data size that corresponds to each person is `2x3`. I utilize a cell for storing data and fill it via random number.(In your case you should use `xlsread('myexcelfile')` to fill this cell). Each ID number is concatenated with a string because Matlab does not accept a string  which  is directly converted by number, for names in rows and columns of the table.

```
clc;clear all;close all;
%  assuming we have got three persons in the dataset 
cell_data=cell(3,3); % I use cell instead of matrix for storing data
ID_number=[38;48;58];% this vector contains the ID numbers of each person

for i=1:numel(ID_number);rng('shuffle');cell_data{i,i}=rand(2,3);end % using  random number as dataset 

ID=strcat('ID ',string(ID_number));%'38' is not a valid variable name so concat number with 'ID ' string 
Customer = string({'Jones';'Brown';'Smith'});
Customer = cellstr(Customer);
T = table('RowNames',Customer); 
for i=1:numel(ID_number)
T.(char(ID(i)))=cell_data(:,i);
end
%
```

After creating our table we can get input as follows:

```
input_cell = inputdlg({'Name','ID number'});% 2x1 cell

ID_input=strcat('ID ',input_cell{2,1});

T( {input_cell{1,1}} , {ID_input} )
```

[image]

And if the input formats are adapted to the table, we can get output like this:

```
  table

             ID48    
         ____________

Brown    [2×3 double]
```

You can add some conditions to the script for the cases that inputs are not adapted to the table format.